# Stop current running thread with certain condition, with finally block being called

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method which is long and has many inner loops, at some point in the inner loop if a certain condition is met, I want the thread to be terminated but I also want the finally block to be called so clean up also happens. How can I do this?

Comment: And you can't surround the logic with a try/finally why?

Comment: it is surrounded, I was thinking about calling Thread.interrupt() but that would skip the finally block. But I will follow xagyg's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `return;` when you want to stop. That will leave the loop and run the finally (so long as the loop with the *return* statement is *within* the `try` block).

E.g.

**pseudocode:**

```
public void run () {
  try {
    loop {
        loop {
           if (condition) return;
        }
    }
  } finally {
    // always run
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that "terminating the thread" really just means-- or should mean!-- that the run() method exits. Put the finally outside the loop, as the last thing in the thread's/Runnable's run() method.